# Browse to same page without refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm a noob with ASP, JS, HTML5.  I'm writing a quick, in-house website that is driven by ASP.net and has Prev and Next buttons.  Each time the user presses the Next button, the next bookmark needs to be scrolled to.  However, it looks to me like the page is refreshed from the server each time.

What is the most straightforward way to create a JavaScript link to the same page without refreshing?  Currently I have spans with id's like '#1' and I'm using

`button onclick="JavaScript:window.location.hash = '#1'`

I've tried many variations and none seem to work.

Please note: I am only trying to navigate to a bookmark on the same page.  No data needs to go to the server, nor does the page need to change in any way.

(edit: changed 'replace' to 'hash' in code as this caused confusion).

Comment: If you're replacing the whole page ... well that's a "refresh".  It doesn't make sense to ask to reload the page without reloading the page, in other words.  Do you just want to reload **part** of the page?

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee Ajax? I think what the OP is asking about is simple hash navigation.

Comment: @AtesGoral - had a second look at the question: you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my button was within a form.  In addition to using window.location.hash='#1', the button *type* must be set to button.  If the button type is not explicitly set, it does a *submit* by default, which is what causes the page refresh.  Otherwise, perhaps the button should not be in a form.

```
<button type='button' onclick="JavaScript:window.location.hash = '#1'">Navigate without refresh
</button>
```

Comment: This is a good argument for providing complete code; this problem would not exist unless the button was inside a form.

Comment: Ah!  Well it is inside a form.  Being a noob I just let Visual Studio create a project for me and it made a form.  I never paid any attention to that tag.  I might remove it now, since I doubt I need it.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `window.location.replace`, try simply assigning to `window.location` or `window.location.href` or `window.location.hash`.

I'm afraid the other answerers either did not understand the question or do not understand the issues. Of course you can jump to a location on a page identified by an ID without reloading it. That's fundamental to how browsers work. That's one reason for the window.location.reload function to exist, so you COULD reload it if you wanted. Nor are you limited to using href's to navigate to the IDs; of course you can do it with window.location (just not with window.location.replace).

UPDATE: There is nothing wrong with what you are trying to do and there is no way the page should be reloading. There must be something else in your page that is causing this behavior, although I cannot imagine what it might be. Try a real simple test case, then work your way up from there.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm asking about!  I have already tried (and re-tried just then) the things you suggest, but they all give identical behavior - the browser jumps to the location first, then it snaps immediately to the start of the document and it appears to refresh.

Comment: @bluedog If you just change `window.location.hash`, the page should stay in the same URL and not refresh.

Comment: got it now.  button type must be set to button.  i've answered my own question but cannot mark it as the answer for two days.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to have some elements with `id` attributes and `<a href>` elements linking to those items with hashes:

```
<h3 id="section_1">Section One</h3>
<p>...</p>
<div>Prev | <a href="#section_2">Next</a></div>

<h3 id="section_2">Section Two</h3>
<p>...</p>
<div><a href="#section_1">Prev</a> | <a href="#section_3">Next</a></div>

<h3 id="section_3">Section Three</h3>
<p>...</p>
<div><a href="#section_2">Prev</a> | Next</div>
```

Something in these lines...

Comment: want buttons though, at the top of the page, rather than in-line links.  the in-line links will not suit the page readability.

Comment: @bluedog Ah. I didn't pay attention to the "buttons" bit. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which can give you the behaviour you are looking for i.e. without refresh of the page, do somethings that involves communicating to the server and getting the response back.